# android transfer excel file to gmail and bluetooth via Only

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

(1) I am trying to send or transfer a excel file from gmail and 
       bluetooth connection only in android mobile.
   (2) My Code is Successfully and file transfer is done.
   (3) when i click my dataTransfer button, it shows more than, one options to send a file
   (4) like gmail and bluetooth and wifi and Messaging and Share to Clipboard 
   (5) I dont want that several options to send a file.
   (6) I need two Share options only-- gmail and bluetooth..

(7) I came across this :
       [How to send file using bluetooth on android programatically?][1]

My Code :

```
 if (curCSV.getCount() != 0) {
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  i.setType("text/plain");
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Diabetic Report File");
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.find_report));
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Via"));
} 
  else
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Note: My Code is Successfully Running.

Note: I want that for, two share options only..
        Please anyone modify my code and help me..
        Thanks Advance..

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution!

Comment: using ResolveInfo class  we can acquire the all installed apps from device,then using packagage name matching we can get the required apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I Found Output for my question. Its working Very Good.

My Code :

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

String blue = "com.android.bluetooth" ;
String gmail = "com.android.gmail" ;

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

 if (!resInfo.isEmpty())
   {

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {

String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
Log.v("hari", "packageName:"+packageName) ;
Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");


 if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("blue") || 
     resolveInfo.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) {

   targetedShareIntent.
   putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Diabetic Report File");
   targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
   "Hello, Please find attached your diabetic report");
Log.v("vivekawe",file.getAbsolutePath()+"");
targetedShareIntent.
    putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath())));


 targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);

 targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);

  Log.v("hari", "targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);:"
  +targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName)) ;

     }  

    Log.v("hari", "After If targetedShareIntents:"+targetedShareIntents) ;
   }
  Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),
  "Select app to share");
  chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.
   toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
  Log.v("hari", "chooserIntent:"+chooserIntent) ;
  startActivity(chooserIntent);
   }
```

Note : 
      This Code is working perfectly.